# TeXnicCenter and Sumatra PDF forward/inverse search off by a few paragraphs

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search

I am using TeXnicCenter 2.0 Alpha 4 and MikTex 2.9 with SumatraPDF 2.0.1.

My forward/inverse search is off by 3-4 paragraphs. Forward/inverse search under DVI and YAP works correctly. My setup is shown below. How do I get my SumatraPDF to forward/inverse search properly?

[image: Profile screenshot 1]
[image: Profile screenshot 2]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem at the moment. Forward and inverse search work properly with all documents I tested. Did you install all recent MiKTeX updates? If so, please provide a short sample document that breaks forward/inverse search on your system. Also provide the generated synctex file, and the complete command-line call of SumatraPDF (entry "Executable Path" at the top of your second screenshot, some options are not visible there).

Comment: The problem is gone now. Maybe it is something specific to that Tex file. The strange thing is, when I created a new blank Tex file, copied over all the contents from the "error version" to the new file (select all, copy, and paste), the error is now gone!